# Remove all characters except alphabet in column rows

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say i have a dataset, and in some columns of these dataset I have lists. Well first key problem is actually that there are many columns with such lists, where strings can be separated by (';') or (';;'), the string itself starts with whitelist or even (';).

For some cases of these problem i implemented this function:

```
g = [';','']
f = []
for index, row in data_a.iterrows():
for x in row['column_1']:
    if (x in g):
        norm = row['column_1'].split(x)
        f.append(norm)
        print(norm)
        else:
```

Actually it worked, but the problem is that it returned duplicated rows, and wasn't able to solve tasks with other separators.

Another problem is using dummies after I changed the way column values are stored:

```
column_values = data_a['column_1']
data_a.insert(loc=0, column='new_column_8', value=column_values)
dummies_new_win =      pd.get_dummies(data_a['column_1'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
```

Instead of getting 40 columns in my case, i get 50 or 60. Due to the fact, that i am not able to make a function that removes from lists  everything except  just alphabet. I would like to understand how to implement such function because same string meanings can be written in different ways:

```
name-Jack  or name(Jack)
```

Desired output would look like this:

```
nameJack  nameJack
```

Comment: Show some example data and your desired output. This will make your question clearer.

Comment: @Rakesh ready, thank you for advice)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood you well, but to remove all non alphanumeric, you can use simple regex.

Example:

```
import re
n = '-s;a-d'
re.sub(r'\W+', '', n)
```

Output: 'sad'

Comment: well yes, but how to implement it in pandas column that consists of lists with str?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace` for pandas `Series`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['name-Jack','name(Jack)']})

df

#         names
# 0   name-Jack
# 1  name(Jack)

df['names'] = df['names'].str.replace('\W+','')

df

#       names
# 0  nameJack
# 1  nameJack
```